# Where else can MS Access get a DSN?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have an access 2000 application to manage. The DSN is pointing to the production Postgresql database and I'd like to point it to the one running on my machine for testing.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to change it. I tried running `odbcad32.exe`, and I did see the DSN and was able to change it to what I wanted (and it did pass the "test connection" test), but it still seems to be connecting to the old production dsn. I confirmed this by checking the connection logs that get dumped to `C:\`. I searched the registry for the production server's name; I could not find it (and I verified that my changes were getting posted to the registry. I searched the entire project's forms' sources for the server name, I could not find it there either.

Where else could Access be getting the dsn from?

Comment: Did you check the individual DSN's for each of your linked tables?

Comment: Where exactly would that be? There aren't any other DSNs in the list. Also, the one that shows up in the connection log is the one I'm editing.

Comment: Have you exited the application, while you are making the changes to the DSN?

Comment: Yes I've tried that. But as I've said, I can see the changes take effect in the registry.

Comment: Maybe the tables aren't linked via the DSN, but via direct connect strings.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use DSNs.  I much prefer DSN-Less connections as it is one less thing for someone to have to configure on each PC and one less thing for the users to screw up.

[Using DSN-Less Connections](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html)

[ODBC DSN-Less Connection Tutorial Part I](http://www.amazecreations.com/datafast/GetFile.aspx?file=ODBCTutor01.htm&Article=true)

[HOWTO: Use "DSN-Less" ODBC Connections with RDO and DAO](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=147875)

[Carl Prothman's Connection String Home Page](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81)

[Relink ODBC tables from code](http://www.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0010.htm)

Also it's easier to have a setup that uses a development connection string for you and a production connection string for everyone else.  For example, assuming your users only get MDEs/ACCDEs, you could use the following function to determine which connection string to use

```
Public Function tt_IsThisAnMDE()
On Error GoTo tagError

  Dim dbs As Database
  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  Dim strMDE As String
  On Error Resume Next
  strMDE = dbs.Properties("MDE")
  If Err = 0 And strMDE = "T" Then
    tt_IsThisAnMDE = True
  Else
    tt_IsThisAnMDE = False
  End If

    Exit Function

tagError:
    Call LogError(Application.CurrentObjectName, "")
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: One advantage of using a DSN, though, is that you don't have to change the linked tables to switch data sources -- all you need to do is alter your DSN to point to a different back end. Kind of like mapped drive letters, dontcha think? ;)

Comment: Hehehe  Hoist by my own comments in the past, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MS Access stores the whole connection string, not just DSN name. Here is what I see opening .mdb file in Notepad:

```
DSN=SQL-Northwind;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=DELLNOTEBOOK;DATABASE=Northwind;Network=DBMSSOCN;Address=LOCALHOST;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

MS Access comes with Linked Table Manager however it won't update DSN once it's changed (at least not for me).

I guess your only choice is to delete a link and create a new one.